# Jabber-net RosterTree error

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, xmpp

Whenever I add the [Jabber-net](http://code.google.com/p/jabber-net/) RosterTree control to my form, I can see that the PresenceManager and RosterManager property values for it have this error listed:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn' to type 'System.ComponentModel.Component'.

I can compile the solution and all but this error keeps popping up randomly. Can someone advice when this may happen. I'm thinking it has to do with the controls not being added properly.

Comment: Can you give us a stack trace?

Comment: actually, i don't need to be running the application for the error to show up. it shows up in the designer mode as well. Btw, thanks for helping with the formatting, dtb!

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the InvokeControl on your JabberClient instance to something that is a Component, like your Form, for instance.  If that fixes the problem, then I know where the bug is.

Comment: actually the jabberclient invokecontrol is already set to the form. it's only when i add a rostertree that i see the errors in the property dialog.

Comment: And do you have a PresenceManager and a RosterManager on that form already?  If so, can you set them manually, rather than letting RosterTreeView find them automatically?